# Swift: Present a popover from another popover

Tags: swift, popover

I want to work with to 2 popovers:

The first popover "popover1" is started from my main ViewController. If the user clicks "next" the popover1 one should be closed and another popover "popover2" should be presented.

Is this possible? I couldn't find a way to dismiss the popover1 after presenting popover2. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Raspbery You should customise UIView and you need to show the customised UIView with animation for present and dismiss. Then use handler for displaying one by one pop views after dismiss.

Comment: @Ram: Thanks for your answer. Do you have a litte example? I am new to swift and I don't really know how to try your advice

Comment: Try with this if you want a custom view as an alert - https://github.com/JSSAlertView/JSSAlertView Otherwise try with this https://github.com/andreamazz/AMPopTip.

Comment: First you need to understand those libraries for alert view or popover whatever you want. Then make customisation based on your requirements, then try to display popover by using with handler feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution how I could reach my goal:

Instead of using 2 different viewController, I only used one viewController with two views: view1 and view2. If I start my popOver, view1 is visible and view2 is hidden. If the user clicks "next", view1 gets hidden and view2 gets visible. That's how I built a litte dialog.

Thanks for your ideas!